# How to see repositories where I am contributor in github?

Tags: git, github, repository

I've contributed to multiple repositories in GitHub. Now, I'm looking for one of them which I forgot its name. How can I find them as a list separately?

The only way I know for this purpose is `Customize your pins` in profile in which all of *your repositories*, *your forked repositories*, and ***contributed repositories*** located together.

Answer (score 0):

You achieve that with the [Github public api](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/rest/reference/search#search-commits) and a little bit of bash and jq.

The API is paginated so you need to get the total number of commits you have on github :

```sh
curl \                                                                                                                                                                                                                            ~ Jungle
  -H "Accept: application/vnd.github.cloak-preview+json" \
  "https://api.github.com/search/commits?q=author:YOUR_USERNAME" \
 | jq '.total_count'
```

You need to divied the `total_count` by 100 to know how many time to paginate.

Then scroll throught the pages:

```sh
for i in {1..NUMBER_OF_PAGES}; do curl \
  -H "Accept: application/vnd.github.cloak-preview+json" \
  "https://api.github.com/search/commits?q=author:YOUR_USERNAME&per_page=100&page=$i" \
 | jq '.items[].repository.full_name' >> /tmp/results.txt; done;
```

Then `sort -u /tmp/results`